# Object with array in localstorage

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make an object with array, every object should have array of file names. I named the object as `productid`, which can have multiple file names. When the customer gives the `productid`, the file names must be displayed in the text area. I have the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <title>W3.CSS</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
        var productid = []
        var filename = []           

        function managerClick(){
            console.log("manager", productid);  
            console.log("manager", filename);  
            productid.push(document.getElementById("productId").value);
            filename.push(document.getElementById("names").value);
            localStorage.setItem("filename", JSON.stringify(filename)); 
            localStorage.setItem("productid", JSON.stringify(productid));  
            var result={}
            productid.map(function(k){
                 result[k]=filename;
            })
            console.log(result);  
            document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = ""; 
            document.getElementById('CustomerpId').value = "";   
        };

    function customerClick(){
    document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = "";
    var CustomerpId = document.getElementById('CustomerpId').value;
    var filenames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("filename"));
    var productIds= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productid"));
    var tempArr = [];
    for(i=0; i< productIds.length; i++) {
        if(productIds[i] == CustomerpId) {
            tempArr.push(i);
        }
    }
    for(i=0; i< tempArr.length; i++) {
        document.getElementById('myTextarea').value += filenames[tempArr[i]] + ",";
    }          
};
        </script>
    <body>
        <div class="w3-card-4 w3-margin" style="width:50%;">         
             <center>Manager</center>

            <div class="w3-container">
                Product Id: <input type="text" id="productId"><br></br>
                File Name: <input type="text" id="names"><br></br>
                <center><button class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey" onclick="managerClick()">Data Entered</button></center><br>
            </div>

             <center>Customer</center>          
            <div class="w3-container">
                Product Id: <input type="text" id="CustomerpId"><br></br>               
                <center>
                    <button class="w3-btn w3-dark-grey" onclick="customerClick()">Click To get filename</button>
                </center><br>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="myTextarea"></textarea>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The issue with this code is that whenever I enter my `productid` in my customer section, the array of all file names is being displayed. I want to display only the array of a specific `productid`:

```
example:  product1[ file1,file2,file3]
          product2[ file1,file2,file3,file4]
          product3[ file1]
```

the array in that product should be displayed, if a specific product is given then data in that product has to be displayed, the above code displays it like this:

[image]

inputs i gave 1 as productid "a,aa,aaa", 2as second productid and "b,bb,bbb" as file name. In my console a,aa,aaa and b,bb,bbb are been displayed in both the products i dont want this to happen. All a,aa,aaa should be in 1st product and all b,bb,bbb should be saved in 2nd product.  Every product should display its own values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
     function customerClick(){
        document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = "";
        var CustomerpId = document.getElementById('CustomerpId').value;
        var filenames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("filename"));
        var productIds= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("productid"));
        var tempArr = [];
        for(i=0; i< productIds.length; i++) {
            if(productIds[i] == CustomerpId) {
                tempArr.push(i);
            }
        }
        for(i=0; i< tempArr.length; i++) {
            document.getElementById('myTextarea').value += filenames[tempArr[i]] + ",";
        }          
    };
```

On Click of Get Field Name, You have to get id for which you want to show and then perform operations on productid array and filenames array.

**EDIT :** As per you mentioned in comments here is updated code:

```
    function managerClick() {
        var productid = document.getElementById("productId").value;
        var filename = document.getElementById("names").value;

        var oldItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(productid)) || [];
        var newItem = filename;
         oldItems.push(newItem);
         localStorage.setItem(productid, JSON.stringify(oldItems));
    }

    function customerClick() {
        document.getElementById('myTextarea').value = "";
        var CustomerpId = document.getElementById('CustomerpId').value;
        var productIds = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(CustomerpId));
        for(i=0;i<productIds.length;i++) {
            document.getElementById('myTextarea').value += productIds[i] + ",";
        }

    }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This works but while saving itself i need to save as i given in that example example:  product1[ file1,file2,file3]
          product2[ file1,file2,file3,file4]
          product3[ file1]. could u help me on this

Comment: What issue is coming? I just updated your `customerClick` code.

Comment: @YokeshVaradhan : I updated my answer please check it